# Test modifications to Jenkins Pipeline shared library without needing a commit

Tags: shared-libraries, jenkins-pipeline

Scenario:
I have a JenkinsFile in a project that references code in a shared pipeline library using `@Library('my-lib')` syntax.  I would like to test changes to my library function without needing to perform a commit to my library repo.

I realize that I can target a specific version or branch of the library in my include statement.  I also realize that I can modify the script in my JenkinsFile without needing a commit by using the "Replay" functionality in the Jenkins UI.  How can I test modifications to the shared library code without needing to do a commit to my branch that I'm testing in?  Right now, we're having to perform a commit with each tweak to our library code, and we'd prefer not to have a super gross commit history.  In other words, we only want commits to our library repo for code that we know is working.

Comment: You have three choices: 1. Replay (best), or 2. Modifying the code directly within the filesystem of Jenkins workspace (bad), or 3. do your testing and development using a docker-based image of Jenkins that is monitoring your local clone so that each commit LOCALLY is what triggers the build, and when you're ready you can squash and push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that I'm either blind, or Jenkins Pipeline now supports editing library code when using "Replay" functionality.  You have to do a commit whenever you're adding a new file to your library to get it to show up on the replay screen.  Once it's there you can edit it without needing to do a commit each time.  Once you're satisfied it's working using replay, then you can commit and push.

Comment: I don t see my shared library in the replay screen.. are you using a plugin?

Comment: @NicolasW You won't see them is they are Global libraries (compared to folder libraries).

Comment: How can I edit library code on Replay if I use global libraries?

Answer (score 7):

For my use case, I wanted to test changes on library variables, created on a different branch.

Since replay will use the ones already set, you need a way to clear them, to confirm that they are loaded properly.

I did not check yet, if there is a "cleaner" way of doing this. It will be the next step.

Here's my workaround:

1. Enter replay and comment the @Library('libname') on the Mainscript (Jenkinsfile)

   ```
   //@Library('libname')
   ```
2. run the build. This will fail as intended and clear the previous replay variables.
3. Enter replay again, uncomment and adjust the library test branch

   ```
   @Library('libname@test-branch')
   ```
4. build should run successfully and replay variables should reflect the changes.